# How to sort by first few letters of string?

Tags: java, sorting

For example, if I have an array of strings `{"Bob", "Bom", "Ash", "Ben"}`, how do I sort it first by first letter (ASCII value), then by second letter, and so on without losing the previous sorted order? so after sorting it would become `{"Ash", "Ben", "Bob", "Bom"}`?

Comment: `Arrays.sort(yourArray);` !?

Comment: Do you mean a **stable sort**? Doing one sort, on A then a second sort not changing the order (or the A sorted list) when the B comparison is equal? Java sorts are stable. You would probably need to sort from last to first. Use `Comparator.comparing`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays` methods in `util` package

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String[] ar = {"Bob", "Bom", "Ash", "Ben"};
      Arrays.sort(ar);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight-forward - use custom Comparator that takes only first N letters (`s.substring(0, N)`):

```
String[] source = {"Bob", "Ben", "Bom", "Ash"};
int N = 2; // sort by first 2 chars

String[] result = Arrays.stream(source)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(0, N)))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

```
String[] names = {"Bob", "Bom", "Ash", "Ben"};
System.out.println(new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(names)));
```